# Play sound when state was change (Android)

Tags: android, audio, notifications

I create live time app ,and I check a link url every 5 second in activity and get string value for result

I check the result same as

```
If oldvalue <> newvalue do 
   Play a sound And Show "Alert" in notification area
```

How can I do that work in behind same as service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither you, nor your users will be happy with this solution.

Since you already have a server, at which you are checking, why don't you implement Push mechanism, whenever there is a new event.

Simple, use Google Cloud Messaging for this, and it is a perfect solution.

You invoke the code for push, when the state changes, and it will alert the user. It can even popup a notification, play a sound, or invoke an activity too (if you want).

let me know if you want any help in implementing GCM.

Use the following links, they are very good.

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your solution ,I didn't use GCM ,How can I start that?

Comment: I just added the links in the post :)

Answer (score 3):

"check link every 5 seconds"
You do realize how much battery that will drain, right ? Just sayin'...

Anyhow, take a look at NotificationCompat class.

Comment: Starting a new URL connection at an interval of less than 0.5 - 1 hour is draining battery. Every minute ? A lot of battery. Every 5 seconds ? You want your user's phone to die in 30 mins ?